# SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Charting - adding a data table to bottom of a chart

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, charts, business-intelligence

I would like to add a data table to bottom of a (line) chart in a report.  I know I can create a matrix report with the same data source.  I would like to have everything lineup automatically like it does when you add a data table to a chart in Excel (as shown at http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/data_table/).

Example from Excel (from above link)
[image: Sample Chart]
<sub>(source: [tushar-mehta.com](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/data_table/index.3.gif))</sub>

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in one go, but this article describes how to.

[Get More Out of SQL Server Reporting Services Charts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128(SQL.90).aspx), see "Adding Chart Data Tables"

Comment: @gbn, thanks but I don't want to create a separate report element linked to the same data source as I need them to lineup as shown in the example from Excel.

Comment: I figured that might be the case.  Thanks for your time, sounds likes this is the answer - granted not the one I hoped for.